# What would be the time complexity of following Genetic Mutation

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, mutation, genetic-programming

```
def mutation(domain, step, solution) -> list:
gene = random.randint(0, len(domain)-1)
mutant = solution
if random.random() < 0.5:
    if solution[gene] != domain[gene][0]:
        mutant = solution[0:gene]+[solution[gene]-step]+solution[gene+1:]
else:
    if solution[gene] != domain[gene][1]:
        mutant = solution[0:gene]+[solution[gene]+step]+solution[gene+1:]
return mutant
```

The following code is of a mutation operator that takes a domain, step size and solution.
It then randomly selects a gene to be modified by the step size depending on the probability of mutation.
I want to know how much time will the random.randint() take for chosing the gene and thus, what will be the time complexity of this mutation operation? Can I assume it to be O(1)?

Comment: There are no loops here.  Clearly, this is O(1).

Comment: @TimRoberts Could provide an explanation pls?

Comment: I did, and so did you.  Time complexity comes from loops and looping operations.  There are no loops here, and no looping/searching operations.  No matter how many genes, domains, or solutions there are, the runtime will be the same.  That's O(1).

Comment: Technically, I suppose the `mutant =` lines are creating a copy of the list.  Copying a list is an O(N) operation, so it's O(N) depending on the length of "solution".

Comment: @TimRoberts So the random.randint() has no role here right? Just to confirm. Also algorithmically I think it's ok to ignore the copying part.

Comment: No.  Random number generators are deterministic.  They generate a number, and then a fixed mathematical sequence reduces the range to your specifications.  The time for `randint` is totally independent of the limits.

Comment: @TimRoberts Oh , yes you are right they are deterministic indeed. So that would be something like an Mersenee Twister? And  O(1) here refers to the amortized complexity?

Comment: Python happens to use Mersenne Twister, and it runs the same number of instructions regardless of the input.  It's not even amortized, it's O(1).  Your algorithm is O(N) because of the copy.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts! I copied it because I got a bit paranoid.

Comment: @TimRoberts well, there *is* a loop here: `solution[0:gene]+[solution[gene]-step]+solution[gene+1:]`, so, it depends on what the OP is asking. If the length of `solution` varies, then this is `O(N)` on the size of `solution`

Comment: Also, to be clear, `mutant = solution` **does not create a copy**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Solution length remains same after mutations

Comment: @Agrover112 that isn't the issue, if the length of `solution` varies *as an input*  then the time (and space) complexity of your function is linear on the length of `solution`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You are contradicting me without reading what I said.  The statements that start `mutant = solution[0:...` DO, in fact make a copy, exactly because of the expression you quoted.